# Livewire doesn't show value from mutator

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to bind a date field (**mydate**) with laravel livewire. Basically I did the following:

In the model, I did a cast and created a mutator and an accessor:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Platform extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'mydate'];

    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'mydate'];

    protected $casts = ['mydate' => 'datetime'];

    public function getCreatedAtBrAttribute()
    {
        return optional($this->created_at)->format('d/m/Y H:i');
    }

    public function getUpdatedAtBrAttribute()
    {
        return optional($this->updated_at)->format('d/m/Y H:i');
    }

    public function getMydateBrAttribute()
    {
        return optional($this->mydate)->format('Y-m-d\TH:i');
    }

    public function setMydateBrAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->mydate = Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

In the component I added the field in rules:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Models\Platform;
use Livewire\Component;

class PlatformForm extends Component
{
    public Platform $platform;

    protected $listeners = ['recordToEdit' => 'editPlatform', 'newRecord' => 'createPlatform'];

    protected $rules = [
        'platform.id' => 'sometimes',
        'platform.name' => 'sometimes',
        'platform.created_at' => 'sometimes',
        'platform.updated_at' => 'sometimes',
        'platform.mydate_br' => 'sometimes',
    ];

    public function mount() {
       $this->platform = $this->makeBlankPlatform();
    }

    public function makeBlankPlatform()
    {
        return Platform::make();
    }

    public function editPlatform(Platform $platform)
    {
        $this->platform = $platform;
    }

    public function createPlatform()
    {
        $this->platform = new Platform();
        $this->platform->created_at = now();
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->platform->id
            ? $this->platform->updated_at = now()
            : $this->platform->updated_at = $this->platform->created_at;

        $this->platform->save();

        $this->emit('refresh');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.platform-form');
    }
}
```

And in the view I added the wire:model, like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input wire:model.defer="platform.name" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mydate_br">My date</label>
        <input id="mydate_br" wire:model.defer="platform.mydate_br" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="created_at">Created at</label>
        <input id="created_at" wire:model="platform.created_at_br" type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="updated_at">Updated at</label>
        <input id="updated_at" wire:model="platform.updated_at_br" type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>
    <hr class="border">
    <div class="text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
            Cancelar
        </button>
        <button wire:click="save" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
            Gravar
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the date stored in the database is not displayed in the input text, however, if I do it in the standard blade way, {{ $platform->mydate_br }}, the value is displayed, but here I lose functionality of livewire binding.

Anyone have a tip to help me resolve this?

Comment: In your Livewire component (the PHP class), how do you define `platform`? It must be a public property of the class.

Comment: Hello @Qirel, I have now edited the content, informing all the codes. Please, could you  check?